# MongoDB value of $limit after $sort changes the order of results in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I faced problems when migrating simple `.find().sort().skip().limit()` to the Aggregation Framework which resulted on broken paging: the same document appeared on multiple pages. Finally, I realized that `$limit` affects the order of `$sort`'s results. Below I'm describing how to reproduce the steps to see the issue (checked on Mongo 3.4.17 and 3.6.7).

```
> // 1. Create a simple coleection and fill it with test data: 
> for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) db.SomeCollection.insert({sortField: "just_some_string"});
> db.SomeCollection.count();
10
>
> // 2. Check, that with .find().sort().limit() the order of results does not depend on the `limit()`'s value:
db.SomeCollection.find().sort({"sortField": 1}).limit(5)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb531"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb532"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb533"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb534"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb535"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
> db.SomeCollection.find().sort({"sortField": 1}).limit(8)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb531"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb532"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb533"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb534"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb535"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb536"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb537"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb538"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
>
> // 3. Logically the same query but using Aggregation Framework
> db.SomeCollection.aggregate([{$sort: {"sortField": 1}}, {$limit: 5}]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb534"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb535"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb532"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb531"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb533"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
> db.SomeCollection.aggregate([{$sort: {"sortField": 1}}, {$limit: 8}]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb538"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb535"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb532"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb534"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb536"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb531"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb533"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3ddf3a07260b77dddb537"), "sortField" : "just_some_string" }
```

My questions are:

1. Why does `.aggregate()` with $sort followed by $limit give different order of results than `.find().sort().limit()`?
2. Why does the order of results in `.aggregate()` depend on value of the `$limit`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All those docs have the same `sortField` value, so the order isn't deterministic. Add a secondary sort on `_id` to guarantee consistent results.

```
db.SomeCollection.aggregate([{$sort: {"sortField": 1, _id: 1}}, {$limit: 5}]);
```

Comment: Do you mean that `.find().sort().limit()` implicitly sorts by `_id`?

Comment: No, unless you add the secondary sort on `_id`, the `find` may return them in a different order as well.

Comment: But `find` really does not have the different order of results depending on `limit` but `aggregate` does. The documentation of MongoDB says that both use `top-k` when `sort` and `limit` together. Moreover, in my real application, I have a filter condition that matches an index and the results of `find` are still predictable and their order doesn't depend on `limit`.

Comment: It just happens that different `$limit` values trigger different ordering with `aggregate`, and doesn't with `find`. But that order is still perfectly valid which is why you need to include the secondary sort to _guarantee_ consistent results.